# How to determine if an attribute is located in origin class or inherited class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

In the code below:

```
class Klass_1:
    a = 1

class Klass_2(Klass_1):
    b = 2

k = Klass_2()
```

It is possible to access both `k.a` and `k.b`, and `hasattr(k, ...)` is `True` for both 'a' and 'b'.

How to determine if an attribute is located in origin class `Klass_2` or inherited class `Klass_1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to check the `__dict__` objects of each class in the MRO (you can use the `vars()` function here to make the code cleaner):

```
def class_for_attribute(instance, attribute_name):
    for cls in type(instance).mro():
        if attribute_name in vars(cls):
            return cls
```

Demo:

```
>>> class_for_attribute(k, 'a')
<class '__main__.Klass_1'>
>>> class_for_attribute(k, 'b')
<class '__main__.Klass_2'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search in `__dict__` attribute of the class object or its super classes. Here is a general function:

```
In [23]: def find_origin(instance, arg):
             if arg in type(instance).__dict__:
                 return 'class'
             elif any(arg in c.__dict__ for c in type(instance).__bases__):
                 return 'super class'
             return "doesn't exist"
   ....: 

In [24]: 

In [24]: find_origin(k, 'a')
Out[24]: 'super class'

In [25]: 

In [25]: find_origin(k, 'b')
Out[25]: 'class'

In [26]: find_origin(k, 'd')
Out[26]: "doesn't exist"
```

As  @Martijn Pieters mentioned in order to search in deeper levels of super classes you need to use `mro` attribute of the class obejct instead of `__bases__`. As a more pythonic way you can use a generator expression within `next()` function:

```
In [38]: def find_origin(instance, arg):
             return next((c for c in type(instance).mro() if arg in c.__dict__), "doesn't exist")
   ....: 

In [39]: find_origin(k, 'a')
Out[39]: __main__.Klass_1

In [40]: find_origin(k, 'b')
Out[40]: __main__.Klass_2

In [41]: find_origin(k, 'c')
Out[41]: "doesn't exist"
```

Comment: This only covers the direct base classes, what if the hierarchy is deeper?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, in that case we can use `mro` as you used. But still this answer is not wrong and hence it doesn't deserve a down vote.;)

Comment: Well, it'd be wrong if this was `class A(object): a_attr = 1`, `class B(A): b_attr = 2`, and `class C(B): c_attr = 3`, and you asked for `a_attr` on an instance of `C`. Your code says the attribute doesn't exist in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed that's what the deeper inheritance means. I just updated with the general approach.